# Why is top breaking history-search-backward in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a line in my .bashrc the following line:

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
```

that causes that when I write "abc" to command prompt and press up arrow, bash searches in history only for commands that start with "abc". All is fine until I run top (and maybe some other applications that I am not sure about, with top, I am sure) when this behaviour is reversed to normal search. However, when I run `bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'`
 in terminal, nothing changes and I have to kill and restart the terminal to get the old behaviour back. Is there a way to reverse it (or prevent it from happening?) This happens in gnome-terminal and xterm in Unity and Gnome Shell. tty seems to be not affected.

My -bashrc on top of stok ubuntu .bashrc is this:

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
# that behaviour is for pageup and pagedown
bind '"\e[5~": previous-history'
bind '"\e[6~": next-history'

# show possibilities if tab ambigious
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
# ignore case when completing, lets see how it works
set completion-ignore-case on


shopt -s cdspell
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HISTFILESIZE=10001
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%h/%d - %H:%M:%S "
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: did you find why this bind is broken after some commands? not necessarily top, but some commands seem to break the bind.

Comment: Top no longer does this for me, but wine dows. I do not know why it is doing it, I am not using it often enough.

Comment: I further searched SO, the fix is to execute `reset`.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactl what I needed to know!

Comment: if you add it as an anwser, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that some misbehaving applications [break the cursor mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122775/42560). The symptoms are similar to when we accidentally `cat` a binary file to terminal.

The fix is to call `reset`. If `Enter` is also broken, then we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> as also mentione [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499473/42560).

As to the original question of why `top` (or in my case some random script that uses escape characters for colorful output) breaks `history-search-backward`. When it is broken, you can run `read` and then hit the arrow keys. Usually it is `\e[A` but when broken it may become `\eOA`. So, one could map that to `history-search-backward` as well, but usually the terminal is not in a very usable state and `reset` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit binds in `/etc/inputrc` file.

I use 'history-search-backward' on all linux systems and I have no problem with top.

If you have problems with editing the file, see my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308603/auto-complete-for-often-used-command-line-commands/308878#308878).

Comment: Hm, you mean adding
`"\e[5C": history-search-backward
"\e[6D": history-search-forward` to that file? Anywhere? I do not understand the #if

Comment: Hm, it works fine in tty, the problem is with (it affects both unity and gnome shell).

Comment: The #if here was mentioned in case that the inputrc file is empty. In that case you could see from my answer what to write in this file.

Comment: Well, editing inputrc does not change anything anyway