# Is there a script we can use to directly view files without going to the respective path?

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, directory

How can I view file contents without going to specific path where file is? Say a file named `List` resides in `/home/test/temp` and I want to view `List` without going to the `/home/test/temp` directory. Is there any script which can make files directly accessible without changing directories?

Comment: `less /home/test/temp` won't change your current directory and will display the content of the file, but Im not sure if that's what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I actually want is to view content of file without going to respective path and then viewing the file by cat filename command

Comment: Is it just one particular file or you want it to work with any file?

Comment: To view any file now i'm doing is  first going to specific path by "cd home/test/temp "and then by using "LS" command I'm getting list of file and then viewing file by "cat filename" command but I want a script so that I can directly view file

Comment: No for this particular file only

Comment: Do you want to call the script from terminal or do you want to right-click on it?

Comment: Call the script from terminal

Comment: You can create an alias `ct` that types cd /home/test/temp for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto complete for often used command line commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308603/auto-complete-for-often-used-command-line-commands)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing "going to directory" and using the full path of file, as I see from comment.  You also seem to be confusing script with just one command. What M. Becerra shows in his answer is a script. Joseph Manley's answer just uses single command.

Here's the thing: you have to specify full path to a file when passing it as argument if these are random files which you want to access at will.

If you have just one file that you know will remain in same location,  there's couple other approaches:

1. Make a symlink to file in your current directory. For example, `ln -s /opt/myfile.txt  symlink2file.txt`
2. Set path to file as variable and use the variable to pass it as argument to a command. `myvar="/opt/somefile.txt ; less "$myvar"`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `cat /home/test/temp/list` in the command line to view the file. You don't need to change to the directory to use cat if you are providing the full path of the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i'll definitely try this script

Answer (score 0):

To display the content of a particular text file is as simple as:

1. Copy the following on an empty document.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   cat /home/test/temp
   ```
2. Save the document with any name, for the example I'll use `FILE_NAME`.
3. Open a terminal and `cd` to the directory where you saved the previous file.
4. Run `chmod 777 FILE_NAME` to allow the file to be executed.
5. Add the previous script to any of the directories given from `echo $PATH`, I suggest `/usr/local/bin`:

   ```
   sudo mv /path/to/script /usr/local/bin
   ```
6. Now simply open a terminal and type the name of the script to see it's content.